# Pdfbox split PDF in multi files with different page Ranges and Filenames

Tags: java, pdf, split, range, pdfbox

I have a question to Apache PDFBox. Is it possible to split a pdf file in diffrent files with diffrent page ranges and file names?

Example:

- page 1 - 5 filename: part1.pdf
- page 6 filename: part2.pdf
- page 7 - 10    filename: part3.pdf
- ...

Comment: I'll let someone else answer this one: PDFBox PDFSplit command line utility. https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html

Comment: I solved the problem with pdfbox with a java application

Comment: Then please delete the question or answer it yourself to avoid orphans.

Comment: @hugi86: It is always recommended to publish your answer for people with same question in future.
Could you please add your solution here?

Answer (score 5):

Hope this will help

```
int fromPage = 1;
int toPage = 5 ;

File pdfFile = new File("<filePath-to-main-pdf>");
pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);

Splitter splitter = new Splitter();

splitter.setStartPage(fromPage);
splitter.setEndPage(toPage);
splitter.setSplitAtPage(toPage - fromPage +1 );

List<PDDocument> lst =splitter.split(pdfDocument);

PDDocument pdfDocPartial = lst.get(0);
File f = new File("<filePath-WithName>");
pdfDocPartial.save(f);
```

Comment: More explanation would improve this answer.

Comment: @CGritton You might want to check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late but here's a solution for future readers.

Using **PDFBOX 2.0+**:

```
private static void splitPdf(int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (document.getNumberOfPages() > 20) {
        System.out.println(document.getDocumentInformation().getTitle());
        try {
            Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
            splitter.setSplitAtPage(endIndex - startIndex + 1);
            List<PDDocument> splittedList = splitter.split(document);
            int start = 1, end = 20;
            for (PDDocument doc : splittedList) {
                doc.save("/home/Downloads/pdfs/" + document.getDocumentInformation().getTitle()
                        + "_" + start + "_" + end + ".pdf");
                start = end + 1;
                end += 20;
                if (end > document.getNumberOfPages()) {
                    end = document.getNumberOfPages();
                }
                doc.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I am calling this method as:

```
splitPdf(1, 20)
```

**Explanation**:

Here, I am splitting pdfs to 20 pages. Feel free to change the number as your need.

Here is the documentation for `.setSplitAtPage()`:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/multipdf/Splitter.html

> **From docs:** This will tell the splitting algorithm where to split the pages. The default is 1, so every page will become a new document. If it was two then each document would contain 2 pages. If the source document had 5 pages it would split into 3 new documents, 2 documents containing 2 pages and 1 document containing one page.

The `start` and `end` variables are used just for file names.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer.
With me it good working

```
    private static void splitPdf(PDDocument document, String fileName, int fromPage, int toPage) {
    if (document.getNumberOfPages() > 20) {
        System.out.println(document.getDocumentInformation().getTitle());
        try {
            Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
            splitter.setStartPage(fromPage);
            splitter.setEndPage(toPage);
            splitter.setSplitAtPage(toPage); 
            List<PDDocument> splittedList = splitter.split(document);
            for (PDDocument doc : splittedList) {
                doc.save(PATH_SAVE_FILE + fileName + ".pdf"); 
                doc.close();                    
            }                 
            System.out.println("Save successful file : " + fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The main statement you may be missing is:

```
splitter.setEndPage(toPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int numberOfPagesFileShouldHave = 50;
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(inputFile);            
    if (document.getNumberofPages() > 50) {
        try {
            int divideIntoFiles = Math.abs(document.getNumberOfPages() / numberOfPagesFileShouldHave) + 1;
            System.out.println("Divide Into FIles =" + divideIntoFiles);
            int startIndex = 1;
            int endIndex= numberOfPagesFileShouldHave; 
                for (int i = 1; i < divideIntoFiles; i++) {
                    Splitter splitter =  new Splitter();
                splitter.setStartPage(startIndex);
                splitter.setEndPage(endIndex);
                splitter.setSplitAtPage(endIndex);
                List <PDDocument> splittedList = splitter.split(document);
                for (PDDocument doc : splittedList) {
                    doc.save("C:\\Work2022\\_darksiderg" + " " + startIndex + endIndex + ".pdf");
                    doc.close();
                    startIndex  = endIndex + 1;
                    endIndex = endIndex + numberOfPagesFileShouldHave;
                }
                }
        }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).